# Azure AD B2C phone factor sign in guest user

Tags: azure, flutter, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am developing an app in flutter that uses Azure AD B2C phone factor as signin/signup, and that part of it Works fine.
But as i have to submit my app to the app store and google play, i need to create some kind of static "guest" login for the testers to use, so that they dont need to user their own phone number and verify it that way through.
But i cant find Any solution to this.
Has anyone had the same issue or are using azure adb2c phone factor as login and found a way to solve the problem?
As its the only way of logging into the app, it is crucial to get working before i can get the app reviewed.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Currently phone factor mock out is not possibile. You can build your own to allow `TOTP (Phone App)` and `Fido2 authenticators`.

Please raise [user voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) feedback. This will help the product team evaluates such feature.